Issue with "No Web Processing" and "Method Not Allowed" Errors After Deploying Django App to Heroku Using Django Deployment
I m deploying my Django app to Heroku, but after following all the necessary deployment steps, I m facing persistent issues. These errors appear after deployment, and I ve tried various troubleshooting methods but haven't resolved the problem.
I Created a Procfile in the root directory of my project containing:
web: gunicorn Django_project.wsgi --log-file -
My requirements.txt file includes gunicorn, Django, and all other dependencies.
Pushed to Heroku:
Scaled Dynos:
Attempted to scale the web dynos using:
bash
heroku ps:scale web=1
Result: Received an error stating no web processes running.
Checked Logs:
The Heroku logs display the following message:
bash
at=error code=H14 desc="no web dynos running"
